# How to define how a file from Sharepoint is opened

Tags: office-365, excel

On our company Sharepoint with have besides others a lot of Excel (xlsx) files. And we have Office 365 installed on our laptops, don't know whether this is important for this question.
When I click one of these xlsx-files, never mind whether in IE or Edge or Chrome, Excel starts on my laptop.
For couple of colleagues something different happens: the online version of Excel starts inside the browser, again never mind which browser. They first have to open the whole library in the Windows Explorer and opened it from there.
Has anyone an idea what to do to change this behaviour, to finally open xlsx (and other files) directly from Sharepoint into the "real" Excel (or whatever) application?

Thanks and cheers,
Wolfgang

Answer (score 0):

Each library has a setting that you can apply to define how a document is opened.  You can access it by going to the library settings and clicking on **Advanced Settings**.  You will find a section labelled **Opening Documents in the Browser**, where you can define the behaviour for opening documents.  You can also set this for the server, but I can't recall where to do that.  Screenshot:

[image: advanced settings for library]

Also, right-clicking on a document in a library will show a context menu where you can open the document in Office or Office online:

[image: context menu for document]